# Creating folders/sub-folders in python

Tags: python, directory

New to coding and need some help. I've gotten so far just can't figure out how to get it to do what i need next.

```
import os
import subprocess
import os.path
import glob
import re
import shutil
import sys
import time

#Server Paths
test_path = 'C:\\Users\\richard.hensman\\Documents\\Test Files'

MYSGS = input("ENTER MY SGS NO: ")
BARCODE = input("ENTER BARCODE: ")
FERT = input("ENTER FERT: ")
MM = input("ENTER MM: ")
DESC = input("ENTER DESCRIPTION (NO SLASHES): ")

newfolder = os.path.join(test_path, MYSGS + "-" + BARCODE + "_" + FERT + "_" + MM + "_" + DESC)
os.makedirs(newfolder)
```

This creates a folder named exactly how i need it however within that folder I need 5 sub-folders: `'3D Final', '3D Model', '3D Model', 'Art', 'Reference'`

Finally inside sub-folder `'Art'` need another sub-folder `'Supplied'`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
for subfolder in ['3D Final', '3D Model', '3D Model', 'Art', 'Reference']:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(newfolder, subfolder))
os.makedirs(os.path.join(newfolder, 'Art', 'Supplied'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you create that particular directory, you can navigate into it using `os.chdir(...)` and then create more as needed.

You'd add these lines at the end of your program:

```
os.chdir(newfolder)
for dir in ['3D Final', '3D Model', '3D Model', 'Art', 'Reference']:
    os.mkdir(dir)

os.mkdir(os.path.join('Art', 'Supplied'))
```

Comment: os.mkdir('Art\\Supplied') under Linux will produce a directory named 'Art\Supplied` rather than a subdirectory Supplied in Art.

Comment: @Błotosmętek Sorry. Realised my mistake. Thanks for that.